# Автоматическое построение конструктора

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

Пишу класс, завожу переменные внутри.

```
public class Prog {

    public String name;
    public String desc;
    public String link;
    public Date start;
    public int width;

}
```

Чтобы они заполнялись при создании экземпляра, нужен такой конструктор:

```
Prog(String name, String desc, String link, Date start, int width) {

      this.name = name;
      this.desc = desc;
      this.link = link;
      this.start = start;
      this.width = width;

}
```

По сути скучная копипаста переменных из класса в конструктор. Можно как-то, чтобы после того, как я наобъявляю переменных, по нажатии какой-нибудь комбинации клавиш создавался соответсвуйщий конструктор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-constructors.html